# Import remote CSV to mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Could someone give me some pointers on how I can create a PHP script to load a remote csv file into a mySQL table?

I have setup the mySQL table with the fields in the CSV and the relevant types.

I believe I could have used the following if the file was on the local system:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

The end solution is going to be a linux server which has a cronjob to run the php script at 4am every morning.  The CSV file will be located in a SFTP share which will require login credentials.  Unfortunately, it cannot be located on the same box.

Taking into account Simons comment below, I am now struggling to get it to import locally:

```
$data = $conn->query('LOAD DATA INFILE ' .$filelocation. ' INTO TABLE wl_transactions FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" IGNORE 1 LINES');
```

Comment: This would be helpful :http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: I believe that is quite outdated now, it doesn't use PDO and from what I understand, LOAD DATA now means you don't have to loop through the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write to the MySQL server's local file system from PHP, you can use the [PHP curl functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to retrieve the remote file, then save it to a local file and finally trigger a `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: Will give it a go and see.  Currently have issues with my LOAD DATA code.  Updated question

Comment: Update: What are you struggling with, now? The query looks fine to me. Did you have a look at the security requirements mentioned in the MySQL manual? (privileges required to run `LOAD DATA INFILE`, file permissions, the `secure_file_priv` server variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work in an WordPress plugin environment, hopefully it can be of some help for you.

I first created an form where the user can select an csv file and select additional settings.

Those settings are in the $this->csv_settings array

```
if(isset($this->csv_settings['ignore'])):
    $ignore = "IGNORE 1 LINES ({{The columns to ignore}})";
else:
    $this->csv_settings['ignore'] = NULL;
endif;

/** @var wpdb $wpdb */
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare('load data local infile \'$this->path_to_file\' into table {{your table name}} fields terminated by \'' . $this->csv_settings['terminated'] . '\' enclosed by \'' . $this->csv_settings['enclosed'] . '\' lines terminated by \'' . $this->csv_settings['lines'] . '\' '. $ignore.';'));
```